Is My Proof of This Set's Property Rigorous?
I have a set $A$ which is a non-empty set of real numbers, and it does not contain zero. The set $A$ satisfies the following properties:

Property $P_1$: For any $x, y \in A, xy \in A$.
Property $P_2$: For any $x, y \in A, \frac{x}{y} \in A$.

I need to prove that if $A$ has property $P_2$, it also has property $P_1$.
Here's my attempt at the proof:

Given $x, y \in A$, since $A$ has property $P_2$, we know $\frac{x}{y} \in A$.
Since $y \in A$ and $0 \notin A$, we have $ \frac{y}{y} = 1 \in A $.
According to property $P_2$, if $y \in A$, then $\frac{1}{y} \in A$.
Now, we have $x \in A$ and $\frac{1}{y} \in A$, so by property $P_2$, $\frac{x}{1/y} = xy \in A$.

Therefore, if the set $A$ satisfies property $P_2$, it also satisfies property $P_1$.
Is this proof rigorous? Are there any logical gaps or improvements that could be made?
I appreciate your help!

Seems fine to me. The wording/formatting feel a little clunky, but it's hard for me to poke at why (beyond the choice of a list, but frankly I like lists), and this is mostly an aesthetic issue you'll improve upon as you write more and more proofs.

The proof is rigorous and quite neat, I would say.

It doesn't make the proof wrong, but step 1 seems pointless, you never actually use the fact that $\frac xy \in A$.

This reminds me of the defintion of a subgroup.
Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group. The a subset $H \subseteq G$ is a subgroup $(H, \cdot)$ of $(G, \cdot)$, if

$H$ is non-empty,
$H$ is closed under $\cdot$ (the group operation): For all $h_1, h_2 \in H$ it is $h_1 \cdot h_2 \in H$ and
$H$ is closed under inversion: For all $h \in H$ it is $h^{-1} \in H$.

One equivalent definition would be:

$H$ is non-empty and
For all $h_1, h_2 \in H$ it is $h_1 \cdot h_2^{-1} \in H$.

In your case we have $(G, \cdot) = (\mathbb{R}^{\times}, \cdot)$, where $\mathbb{R}^{\times}=\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$. The second definition is equal to your property $P_2$ and because that implies already the closure under the group operation, which is equal to your property $P_1$, that should answer your question.
The proof of the equivalence of these two definitions of a subgroup uses the same argumentation like you in the concrete case of your example.
